# DHCP on Access Point vs DHCP on Router

Tags: cisco, router, dhcp, access-point, capwap

At an accommodation house for our company staff, We have about 10 Access Points and they are all connected to a Router, which is then connected to an optical fiber internet connection. The Access Points don't have static IPs.

Due to the fact that most of the Access Points are old Cisco WAP2000, initially we had issues with devices connecting to the network especially Apple devices. That issue was mostly resolved by keeping the security at WEP standard (I know it is not secure but we can ignore that in this case). 
Now, to resolve further connectivity issues, I was thinking about activating DHCP on the APs, so the devices will get IPs directly from APs rather than putting load on the main Router. Is it a good idea in this case? or is it generally good or bad to have DHCP activated on AP rather than asking Router to assign IPs to devices connected?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

DHCP server doesn't consume many resources, you will have very little gain by removing it from the router, and it will be more difficult to manage.

but anyway, according to [this documentation, page 67](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/csbap/wap2000/administration/guide/WAP2000_Admin_Guide.pdf) you cannot use your AP as DHCP servers:

> Can the WAP2000 Access Point act as my DHCP Server?
>   No. The WAP2000
>   Access Point is nothing more than a wireless hub, and as such  cannot
>   be configured to ha ndle DHCP capabilities

(additionally if you have a single layer 3 network with multiple AP, it doesn't make sense)

Comment: That's strange because the WAP2000 AP settings have section dedicated to DHCP server functionality? Hence I asked the question. If this AP is not capable of that then why include it in the settings?

Comment: So it seems the documentation I found doesn't apply to your AP. Can you check the full product number?